# Post files from ASP.NET Core web api to another ASP.NET Core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

We are building a web application that consist of an Angular2 frontend, a ASP.NET Core web api public backend, and a ASP.NET Core web api private backend.

Uploading files from Angular2 to the public backend works. But we would prefer to post them forward to the private backend.

Current working code

```
[HttpPost]
public StatusCodeResult Post(IFormFile file)
{
  ...
}
```

From there I can save the file to disk using file.CopyTo(fileStream);

However, I want to re-send that file, or those files, or, ideally, the whole request to my second web api core.

I am not sure how to achieve this with the HttpClient class of asp.net core.

I've tried all kinds of things such as

```
StreamContent ss = new StreamContent(HttpContext.Request.Body);
var result = client.PostAsync("api/Values", ss).Result;
```

But my second backend gets an empty IFormFile.

I have a feeling it is possible to send the file(s) as a stream and reconstruct them on the other side, but can't get it to work.

The solution must use two web api core.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Solution

Public backend in DMZ

```
[HttpPost]
public StatusCodeResult Post(IFormFile file)
{
    try
    {
        if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(currentPrivateBackendAddress);
                    
                    byte[] data;
                    using (var br = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
                        data = br.ReadBytes((int)file.OpenReadStream().Length);

                    ByteArrayContent bytes = new ByteArrayContent(data);

                    
                    MultipartFormDataContent multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    
                    multiContent.Add(bytes, "file", file.FileName);

                    var result = client.PostAsync("api/Values", multiContent).Result;
                    

                    return StatusCode((int)result.StatusCode); //201 Created the request has been fulfilled, resulting in the creation of a new resource.
                                                
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return StatusCode(500); // 500 is generic server error
                }
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(400); // 400 is bad request

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return StatusCode(500); // 500 is generic server error
    }
}
```

Private backend

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post()
{
    //Stream bodyStream = HttpContext.Request.Body;

    if (Request.HasFormContentType)
    {
        var form = Request.Form;
        foreach (var formFile in form.Files)
        {
            var targetDirectory = Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");

            var fileName = GetFileName(formFile);

            var savePath = Path.Combine(targetDirectory, fileName);

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                formFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }                   
        }
    }          
}
```

Comment: This solution is not that good as you are loading whole thing in the memory in public backend - just imagine if you have file more than your RAM can accommodate....

Comment: This is the only solution that seems to work for me. @GeorgeAnisimov do you know of an alternative?

Comment: Seems to work well for my gateway file pass through. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: It is not necessary to convert to ByteArrayContent, you can add StreamContent object with something like:
            multiContent.Add(new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream(), "file", file.FileName));

Comment: hi. I also want to send a param with this particularly for user I am uploading this file. I need to send userId with this request. Can you also help with that? and also one thing more. how can I use postman to hit this specific upload api? what shall be its body?

Comment: The answer minohimself provided seems better if you do not want to store the file in memory before forwarding it to another endpoint. Like George Anisimov pointed out, doing it this way might lead to issues with large files.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to understand the use of  MultipartFormDataContent in a better way

Answer (score 15):

Hi i had the same issue and this is what worked for me :

My setup is netCore MVC netCoreApi.

My MVC Controller looks like :

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    Sp4RestClient dataPovider = new Sp4RestClient("http://localhost:60077/");

    long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
       await dataPovider.ImportFile(file);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

DataProvider Method :

```
public async Task ImportFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient(_queryBulder.BuildImportFileRequest());

        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            content.Add(new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                Headers =
                {
                    ContentLength = file.Length,
                    ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType)
                }
            }, "File", "FileImport");

            var response = await restClient.Post<IFormFile>(content);
        }
    }
```

And least my WebApi Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("ImportData")]
public IActionResult Import(IFormFile file)
{         
    return Ok();
}
```

To see the complete code here is my RestClient Post method :

```
public async Task<RestResult<T>> Post<T>(HttpContent content)
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(Endpoint, content);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                return new RestResult<T> { Result = result, ResultCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
            }
            RestResult<T> nonOkResult =
                new RestResult<T> { Result = default(T), ResultCode = response.StatusCode, Message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() };
            return nonOkResult;
        }
    }
```

// Yeah i know im not getting HttpStatusCode.Created back ;)

happy coding ;)

Answer (score 2):

**API Code**

```
 [Route("api/upload/{id}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string id)
    {
        var filePath = @"D:\" + id; //+ Guid.NewGuid() + ".png";
        if (Request.HasFormContentType)
        {
            var form = Request.Form;
            foreach (var formFile in form.Files)
            {
                if (formFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return Ok(new { Path = filePath });
    }
```

**Back End**

```
        [Route("home/UploadFile")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
            return Content("file not selected");

        var client = new HttpClient();

        byte[] data;
        using (var br = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            data = br.ReadBytes((int)file.OpenReadStream().Length);
        ByteArrayContent bytes = new ByteArrayContent(data);
        MultipartFormDataContent multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
        {
            { bytes, "file", file.FileName }
        };
        var result = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:2821/api/upload/" + file.FileName, multiContent).Result;
        return RedirectToAction("file");
    }
```

---

[Download Source](https://github.com/godlymathew/Core-File-upload-api)

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation - I needed a proxy method for forwarding not only files but also JSON data and whatnot. I did not want to do any analysis of the data in my proxy to let the final receiver deal with it.

So with some help from  [@Anton Tykhyy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061864/217823) I came to the following working solution:

```
byte[] arr = null;
using (var mems = new MemoryStream())
{
    // read entire body into memory first because it might be chunked with unknown length
    await request.Body.CopyToAsync(mems);
    await mems.FlushAsync(); // not sure if needed after CopyToAsync - better safe then sorry
    arr = mems.ToArray();
}

msg.Content = new ByteArrayContent(arr);
msg.Content.Headers.ContentLength = arr.Length;

// keep content-type header "as is" to preserve multipart boundaries etc.
msg.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", request.ContentType);

var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(msg);
```

I tested it with complex request that contained multipart form data with JSON field and multiple attached files, and all the data reached my backend server without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the HttpClient when you call the private backend API, can you reference the private Core API project from the public Core API project and call the controller directly from the Core API project? See the request is still null/empty. If the request comes out with a value then the issue is with the use of the HttpClient.

Ideally, you want to create a package library(kind of SDK) for your private Core API that you want to distribute to consuming clients. This acts like a wrapper/proxy. This way you can isolate the private backend system and you can troubleshoot it in isolation. So you public Core API project(which is the private backend client) can reference it as nuget package.