# Forwarding the entire received request "as is" using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have a thin frontend API web service that does some preprocessing on the received data and then sends the data to my backend API web service using HttpClient.

There are some complex cases when a request contains multipart data with JSON and files, and I don't want to parse it at all in the frontend. The backend will do the job.

So, I would like to take the request "as is" - as raw as possible (not caring about its contents and whether it's multipart or not) and just forward it to the backend API.

I tried the following:

```
var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, resourceUrl);
msg.Content = new StreamContent(request.Body);
var apiResponse = await _httpClient.SendAsync(msg);
```

but the backend web service receives an empty request body with 0 length.

**How do I forward the entire request body without having to analyze it and reassemble a new request body?**

Comment: Maybe use url rewriting to intercept the more complex requests based on url pattern and proxy them on without involving the rest of the pipeline?

Comment: @CaiusJard  Good idea, but unfortunately I have no control over the hosting infrastructure to be able to proxy requests at the server level.

Comment: You're at the wrong API level.  Use HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient for explicit access to headers and request stream.  You'll need to transform/copy the incoming request URI and all teh request headers, then copy the incoming request body stream to the outgoing request body stream.  Then do the reverse on the response.

Comment: Why don't you only change the URL or the original request and send it:
`request.RequestUri = new Uri("destination");
await _httpClient.SendAsync(request)`

Comment: @Alberto  Wrong datatype for SendAsync: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage'`

Comment: David: what are you talking about? In netcore, HttpWebRequest is a wrapper around HttpClient/HttpXxxMessage. How can supposedly "lower level" API (HttpWebRequest) be a wrapper around a supposedly "higher level" API (HttpClient)?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I'm also curious what you meant by "wrong API level". Could you expand on that? Not doubting you, you obviously have the creds. Even though the question has been answered, I think an alternative answer with your approach could be very insightful.

Comment: HttpClient is optimized for ease-of-use.  You can access _most_ of the protocol details you would need.  But for explicitly managing the exact HTTP protocol details of a request and response HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse is a "lower level" api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `msg.Content.ContentLength` for this to work correctly. It's also a good idea to copy `ContentType` and other content headers from the request into `msg.Content`, so that your backend service knows how to parse it.

Comment: Thanks, your advice led me to the following working solution: `await request.Body.CopyToAsync(mems); await mems.FlushAsync(); msg.Content = new ByteArrayContent(mems.ToArray()); msg.Content.Headers.ContentLength = arr.Length;
msg.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", request.ContentType); var apiResponse = await _httpClient.SendAsync(msg);` - it correctly passed through entire multipart form with mixed JSON data and attachment files.

Comment: `HttpClientHandler` is supposed to do buffering for you if the length of the content is unknown (see reference source), but sometimes one needs to prod it to do its job.